# Java collection supporting: duplicate values, fast add, fast remove, fast min value?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, guava

**Question:** does anybody know of a Java implementation (I have too little time/knowledge to develop my own right now) of a collection with the following characteristics?

- fast add
- fast random-access remove
- fast minimum value
- duplicates

**Condensed (oversimplified) version of use case is:**

- I have a class that keeps track of 'time', call it `TimeClass`
- Events start at monotonically increasing times (**times are not unique**), but can finish in any order
- When events start they report their start time to `TimeClass`
- When events finish they again report their start time to `TimeClass`
- `TimeClass` adds an event's start time to a *collection** when the event starts (**fast add**)
- `TimeClass` removes an event's start time from that *collection** when the event finishes (**fast random-access remove**)
- `TimeClass` is capable of reporting the lowest not-yet-finished start time (**fast minimum value**)

*** think of *collection* as: `Collection<Time> implements Comparable<Time>`

Because I'm not sure what the runtime behavior of my system (the system in which `TimeClass` lives) will be, I've quickly benchmarked the following scenarios using these collections: `TreeMultiSet` (Guava), `MinMaxPriorityQueue` (Guava), `ArrayList`.

Note, depending on the collection used, *min value* is achieved in different ways (remember elements are added in increasing order): `TreeMultiSet.firstEntry().getElement()`, `MinMaxPriorityQueue.peekFirst()`, `ArrayList.get(0)`.

ADD 1,000,000:

- `TreeMultiSet`: **00:00.897 (m:s.ms)**
- `List`: **00:00.068 (m:s.ms)**
- `MinMaxPriorityQueue`: **00:00.658 (m:s.ms)**

ADD 1, REMOVE 1, REPEAT 1,000,000 TIMES:

- `TreeMultiSet`: **00:00.673 (m:s.ms)**
- `List`: **00:00.416 (m:s.ms)**
- `MinMaxPriorityQueue`: **00:00.469 (m:s.ms)**

ADD 10,000 IN SEQUENTIAL ORDER, REMOVE ALL IN SEQUENTIAL ORDER:

- `TreeMultiSet`: **00:00.068 (m:s.ms)**
- `List`: **00:00.031 (m:s.ms)**
- `MinMaxPriorityQueue`: **00:00.048 (m:s.ms)**

ADD 10,000 IN SEQUENTIAL ORDER, REMOVE ALL IN RANDOM ORDER:

- `TreeMultiSet`: **00:00.046 (m:s.ms)**
- `List`: **00:00.352 (m:s.ms)**
- `MinMaxPriorityQueue`: **00:00.888 (m:s.ms)**

**Current thoughts:**

I'm leaning towards using `TreeMultiSet` as it has the most stable performance and seems to degrade most gracefully. **I WOULD LOVE MORE SUGGESTIONS**

Thanks

**--EDIT--**

Example pseudo code of *ADD ALL IN SEQUENTIAL ORDER, REMOVE ALL IN RANDOM ORDER*:

```
benchmark(){
    int benchmarkSize = 1000000;
    int benchmarkRepetitions = 100;
    Duration totalDuration = Duration.fromMilli(0);
    TimeClass timeClass = new TimeClassImplementation();
    for (int i = 0; i < benchmarkRepetitions; i++)
        totalDuration += benchmarkRun(timeClass,benchmarkSize);
    System.out.println(totalDuration);
}

Duration benchmarkRun(TimeClass timeClass, int count){
    List<Time> times = createMonotonicallyIncreasingTimes(count)

    // monotonically increasing times to add from
    List<Time> timesToAddFrom = copy(times)

    // random times to remove from
    List<Time> timesToRemoveFrom = shuffleUniformly(copy(times))

    Time startTime = now()

    // add all times
    for(Time time: timesToAddFrom) {
        Time min = timeClass.addTimeAndGetMinimumValue(time);
        // don't use min value
    }

    // remove all times
    for(Time time: timesToRemoveFrom) {
        Time min = timeClass.removeTimeAndGetMinimumValue(time);
        // don't use min value
    }

    Time finishTime = now()

    return finishTime - startTime;
}
```

Comment: "I've quickly benchmarked the following scenarios". How did you do that? Show us your benchmark code.

Comment: minimum value depends on value itself or on adding order?

Comment: @Tichodroma, two points: (1) I've added some pseudo code now (assume that the timeClass instances passed in have different underlying implementations, using different collections) (2) there was an error in my code where I ran LinkedList twice and MinMaxPriorityQueue never, I am rerunning to get MinMaxPriorityQueue numbers now

Comment: @udalmik the value itself Time implements Comparable<Time>

Comment: I've edited the results now, to show corrected values for MinMaxPriorityQueue performance. I used 10,000 instead of 1,000,000 in some tests for two reasons: (1) tests take too long otherwise (2) MinMaxPriorityQueue seems to have a bug where it loses values if the collection size is too large (i.e. remove(Time) returns false)

Comment: The bad news is that benchmarking in Java is much harder than expected. The results of any measurement taking a fraction of second are essentially just (low quality) random numbers, unusable for anything, only slightly correlated to real use performance (after the code gets warmed up, etc.). See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/581205).

Comment: thanks @maaartinus very useful resource! FYI, (1) I've run longer tests (up to 15s) too and (2) I'm only really comparing those numbers as an orders-of-magnitude comparison in the scenarios I consider most important -> "ADD 10,000 IN SEQUENTIAL ORDER, REMOVE ALL IN RANDOM ORDER"

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is a tree map:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

O(log n) pretty much for all operations.. you can get your keys back sorted.

There is also a MinMaxPriorityQueue from Google (guava)

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MinMaxPriorityQueue.html

the remove is O(n) though, all other operations are O(log n)

Comment: As explained in my question, I have tried MinMaxPriorityQueue already. Also, without a wrapper around it, how would TreeMap fit my needs?  I have no keys because Times can have duplicate values. I **could** keep a counter in the value (e.g., Map<Time,Integer>) but wouldn't that be duplicating what the Guava TreeMultiSet already offers? (I realize that perhaps the standard Java TreeMap would have a faster implementation, but I am skeptical...)

Comment: Sure, and I appreciate the input, but making keys unique changes the problem

Comment: @user1500191: What you're talking about is totally beside the point. It's possible for a data structure to have non-unique entries without sacrificing performance. In the case of something like a `Multiset`, it's pretty straightforward to just store unique elements along with the _count_ of each element internally, while presenting that as multiple copies of the same element through the API.